# How did Bonnie get the scars on her back?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-craft

In [*The Craft*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115963/), Bonnie has burn scars on her back that become part of  important plot points in the film.

[image: Bonnie]

Her scars are not discussed very much, but she is obviously extremely self-conscious about them. There is some discussion about them by her classmates:

> And the one in the middle, she's got burn scars all over her
>   body.  I haven't seen them, but friends of mine have.  Anyway,
>   they're--Nah.  Never mind.

**Is it ever revealed how Bonnie got the scars on her back?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, it is never revealed how Bonnie got the scars on her back in the movie.

However, there are many sources claiming that she got those scars in a fire incident in her childhood.

From [this Indiewire article](http://www.indiewire.com/2013/10/we-are-the-weirdos-mister-revisiting-the-craft-208023/),

> Each of the witches in The Craft has something personal that she’s struggling with. Though these struggles aren’t the focus of the film, they’re
>   not simple problems. **Bonnie was burned badly as a child and has scars covering most of her back that she is ashamed of.**

From [Wikia](http://thecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Bonnie),

> Bonnie is a main character in The Craft. She is a practicing witch. Bonnie is presented as a shy, insecure young girl who suffers from burn scars along her back and shoulders **which she acquired from a fire incident when she was a child.**

There is no authentic source I could find, but multiple sources do mention that.

Comment: I'd have to rewatch, but I'm fairly sure it was mentioned in the movie that this is indeed the case.

Comment: If the movie doesn't say that's the case [it could be a scenario of citogenesis.](https://xkcd.com/978/)